# How to send data to parent activity when up button is pressed

Tags: java, android

Im able to send data to parent activity when back button is pressed.
However, for up button i cannot implement similar logic and data is not getting returned to parent activity why is that ?

```
 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
            case android.R.id.home:
                NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
               ..... 
            Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
            resultIntent.putExtra("noteJSON", noteJSON.toString());
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
            this.finish();

                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Im using `startActivityForResult` to start childactivity. On `onactivityresult` basically handling the intent info. When back, button is pressed its working. When UP is pressed `onactivityresult` never gets executed. Thats the problem

Comment: please show what are you doing to get data in parent activity.

Comment: can you show the code of parent activity where u are starting the child activity and your onactivityresult

Comment: Im using startActivityForResult to start child. On onactivityresult basically handling the info. When back, button is pressed its working. when up is pressed onactivityresult never gets executed. Thats the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `navigateUpFromSameTask` method, it finishes the current activity and starts (or resumes) the appropriate parent activity. If the target parent activity is in the task's back stack, it is brought forward. As a result `onActivityResult` won't be called.

If you want to ensure result is returned via `onActivityResult` then remove call to `navigateUpFromSameTask` as follows:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
        case android.R.id.home:

        ....
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
        resultIntent.putExtra("noteJSON", noteJSON.toString());
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
        this.finish();

        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Its still ot working. onActivityResult is not getting called. Iv verified the code in onOptionsItemSelected is getting executed, but not onActivityResult

Comment: So why removing  NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this); made it work

Comment: @32a I have provided the explanation in the answer. Let me know in case its unclear

Answer (score 0):

try below

```
  case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
           ..... 
            startActivity(new Intent(YourActivity.this,ParentActivity.class).putExtra("noteJSON", noteJSON.toString()));


            return true;
```

Comment: not working mean only data not passing or intent not working

Comment: when i press up button, it go back to parent, but data doesnt get updated. but for back, it works correctly

Comment: onActivityResult is not getting called. thats why